# What would be the fastest way to achieve the equivalent of mysql - "truncate tablename" for IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am trying to find the fastest way to clear an `object_store` (table) of its data in `IndexedDB`.

Consider there are 5000+ records being stored.

I thought of just `.deleteObjectStore` but it creates the following `error`:

```
InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.
```

It seems you can `create` or `delete` an `object_store` only in a `versionchange transaction`.

What would be the fastest way to achieve the equivalent of `mysql` - `truncate tablename` for `IndexedDB` when the `database` is connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [IDBObjectStore.clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore.clear) ?

Comment: same issue as `.deleteOjectStore` gives the `mutation error`. Seem like `.clear` and `.deleteObjectStore` can only be ran during the `versionchange transaction`. Unless im doing something wrong. Here is what I tried.   `var store = db.obj.transaction(['cow']).objectStore('cow'); store.clear();`

Comment: k, just tested this in FireFox and gave me an error : `TypeError: store.clear is not a function` Here is the code i used : `var store = db.obj.transaction(['cow'],'readwrite'); store.clear();`

Comment: i have to add `store.objectStore('cow').clear()` kind of silly of me not to think of that